# How to return a static xml file from nodejs server

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am integrating a 3rd party template which has a slideshow written using Mootools. The nodejs is configured with express and ejs

The data for the slideshow comes from a few xml files. For example data.xml. I placed the data.xml in public folder and added the following code to server.js (the main file)

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.post('/data.xml', function(req, res){
    res.contentType('application/xml');
    res.sendFile('/data.xml');
});
```

Unfortunately this does not seems to work. I can see the file if I type the url
http://localhost:8080/data.xml

But the response I see in firebug is 
" Cannot POST /data.xml "

I am assuming Mootools is trying to access the file using some POST method. Any suggestions for this problem?

Comment: http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Answer (score 2):

when you are sending the file with sendFile() you need to point to the absolute address check this. note that I have the data.xml in the main folder.

you can access the file with localhost:8080/data (not localhost:8080/data.xml) and also as this is a post, you cannot access it through browser. use postman instead. or if you need it to be accessible on browser you need to change the protocol to get.

```js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();

// you don't need this line!
// app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname)));


app.post('/data', function(req, res){
    res.contentType('application/xml');
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname , 'data.xml'));
});



var server = app.listen(8080, () => {
 console.log('Started listening on 8080');
});
```

Comment: hello I am trying to do as stated above but on the browser i get an error This page contains the following errors:
error on line 8 at column 38: AttValue: " or ' expected
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.. Yet i have used https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/ to generate the site map